# Twitter API returns callback to '127.0.0.1:8001' on production server. Why?

Tags: django, callback, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

Everything is working on my site, except when I'm trying to log in with `twitter` through `python-social-auth`. It worked well on my local development server, but when I went into production, after the `twitter` login, it sends the response to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/complete/twitter....`.

I am using `gunicorn`+`nginx` without too much knowledge about it, except that i've used it for other projects without problems. Although, I have binded gunicorn `--bind 127.0.0.1:8001`. Is that the problem? I tried using `--bind mydomain.com:8001` but that gives me a `502 Bad Gateway` response.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code. And what is the callback url set in the Twitter app?

Comment: check your twitter oauth app redirect url

Comment: Sounds like your application ran by gunicorn doesn't know that's behind a proxy and the real URL for it, try defining `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` and `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` in your nginx conf.